# background for textview can be scaled programmatically?

Tags: android, background, textview

i need to create balls with numbers in the middle .  i need about 10-11 balls in a row so i use weight . 
but my balls (background's for textview don't think dirty) are not circle . i want them to save there own proportions .

```
LayoutParams textParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.09f);

            resultNumber = new TextView(context);
            resultNumber.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ball_golden);
            resultNumber.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            resultNumber.setLayoutParams(textParams);
            resultNumber.setText("6");
            resultLayout.addView(resultNumber);
```

this is the code , resultNumber added about 10 time for each row .

thanks for your time (-:

Answer (score 0):

You can use a relative layout and position the text view in center for each item. Apply the background resource to the relative layout.

Comment: the text is in the center , the problem is the background that become from circle to elipstic